# Texpad: Snippets for replacing in-text references

Tags: macros, pdftex, texpad, macos, code-snippets

I enjoy the feature of Texpad allowing creating own snippets. My snippets are rather simple and use `insert at cursor` function only. However, I was wondering whether one can make more sophisticated snippets that would replace and insert command at cursor. Namely:

1. **In-text references**: Make a snippet that would replace, e.g., `[1]`, `[4,5,6]` by `\cite{1}` and `\cite{4,5,6}` when selecting `[1]` and `[4,5,6]` by cursor and then using the snippet.
2. **Table referencing**: This would require probably a similar principle, but still... I would like to also create snippet that would substitute, e.g. `Table 4` for `Table~\ref{table4}` if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: These replacements seem a bit strange, the `[1]` and `[4,5,6]` and `Table 4` labels are not supposed to be present in the source of the document but only in the output. The labels could be in the source if the source is copied from a pdf, but then the corresponding LaTeX code that would make the referencing work (`\label{table4}` for example) would also be missing, and the same for the citations in a `.bib` file. Moreover, it is advised to give table/figure references and cite keys descriptive names instead of numbers, and let LaTeX handle the numbering.

Comment: So maybe you can explain a bit more about your use case, what is the code of your document, how did you get that code, what is your goal in editing the document?

Comment: @Marijn I agree 100 % that citing or referring plainly by numbers is not recommended as it not as clear as using names or authors. In the aforementioned case, this file would be a copy of .pdf / .docx into the LaTeX (sort of mini-articles), as you mentioned, where the referencing is done by the ISO Standard References. Regardless of the correct format, my point was to make a snippet that would insert a text and simultaneously replace some characters as it would be useful for my purposes, such that I can quickly convert the references in the LaTeX code.

Comment: @Marijn From the [Texpad documentation](https://www.texpad.com/docs/apps/workspace/editor/snippets), there seems to be only three possible hotkeys: `ctrl key`, `group`, `insert at cursor` by which I cannot imagine making the aforementioned substitution. However, maybe I have missed something, hence I asked.